# No module named 'PIL' althought the installing command

Tags: python, import, python-imaging-library

When I write `from PIL import Image` I get this error :`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`
So I wrote many times in my cmd : `pip import pillow` and he shows me that : `Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\rusti\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (8.2.0)`

I also tried to refresh my desktop, and to restart my IDLE.
I have no idea where the error comes from...

Comment: Can you type `python -m pip install pillow`, and then `python -c "import PIL"` to test it?

Comment: He can't recognize the word python. That's strange, because I've written this line `C:\Users\rusti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39` in my environnment variable

Comment: @Dennis I don't know what has been changed but now he can recognize the python keyword in my shell. So I typed the commands you told me :
For the first command, he says that the requirement is already satisfied
For the second one, nothing happens in the shell, and I still have this error `No module named 'PIL'`

Comment: It's been hours now I'm working on that error, please help me... I saw all the possibles videos on youtube and it dosen't work for me.

Comment: How do you run Python scripts usually?

Comment: In pycharm, or I put the file on the desktop and double click on it

Comment: One thing I just noticed, and I think it's important to specify it, when I install the pillow module, I didn't give you the whole shell message, so that's the complete result of my installation : `Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\rusti\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (8.2.0)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\rusti\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)` And the warning message is in yellow

Comment: See if you can find where `python.exe` is on your computer. Then run `C:\\[whatever you find]\python.exe -m pip install pillow`. Then run your programs with `C:\\[whatever you find]\python.exe C:\\[whatever]\\file_you_want_to_run.py`

Comment: I typed this command, and again, I got the message I told you before : `Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\rusti\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (8.2.0) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\rusti\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)`, and then I ran my program in PyCharm, and again I got the `No module named 'PIL'` error

Comment: Sorry @Dennis to not giving news about my problem, I thought a long time and I think the problem comes from the fact that I write all my codes on a USB stick. My hypothesis is, that python installs PIL on my computer, but it has to be on the stick. So I'm still trying now to do this installation, but I've got a clue

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I think my problem is solved but it was really hard, and python and python are very difficult for me